# Spring Exception handling, different view for different urls

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I have an exception resolver that catches exceptions and returns view accordingly.

```
<bean class="com.mycomp.project.util.MyExceptionResolver">
<property name="exceptionMappings">
    <props>
        <prop key="com.mycomp.project.domain.exception.PermissionException">permissionException</prop>
        <prop key="com.mycomp.project.controller.payment.PaymentException">paymentException</prop>
        <prop key="com.mycomp.project.domain.exception.CSRFException">csrfException</prop>
        <prop key="com.mycomp.project.domain.exception.KeyEncryptionKeyException">keyEncryptionKeyException</prop>
        <prop key="java.lang.Exception">exception</prop>
    </props>
</property>
<property name="defaultErrorView" value="exception" />
```

Everything's fine.

But I have separate Views & Controllers for two parts of my web application for which I need to handle exceptions and need to display a different view than the others. So all I need is a different view if the exception happens:

*myproject/admin/*,

different view for:

*myproject/user/*.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a [HandlerExceptionResolver](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerExceptionResolver.html) and on your `resolveException` method you could add a prefix on the view lookup based on which handler was being executed.